# Get $(this) while onclick event triggered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Most time I use a jQuery event handler to do CSS styling. And this is the first time I try to accomplish this by using the HTML event attribute. Here's my code:

```js
$('.navBtn').on('click', function() {
  var length = $(this).closest('.videoList').find('.slider').length;
  alert(`length A = ${length}`);
});

function btnClick() {
  var length = $(this).closest('.videoList').find('.slider').length;
  alert(`length B = ${length}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="videoList">
  <div class="navBtn" onclick="btnClick()">Button</div>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li>items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

The result of length A is 1 and length B is 0.
I think it's probably that I mixed use jQuery with other stuff. But I want to know more details. Please explain to me or show me the information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `this` to the function:

```
onclick="btnClick(this)"
```

Then the function just accepts it as a parameter:

```
function btnClick(element) {
```

For example:

```js
$('.navBtn').on('click', function() {
  var length = $(this).closest('.videoList').find('.slider').length;
  alert(`length A = ${length}`);
});

function btnClick(element) {
  var length = $(element).closest('.videoList').find('.slider').length;
  alert(`length B = ${length}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="videoList">
  <div class="navBtn" onclick="btnClick(this)">Button</div>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li>items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

But this is kind of a step in the wrong direction.  If you're using jQuery, use jQuery.  In lieu of jQuery, you can still attach the event handler in code:

```js
$('.navBtn').on('click', function() {
  var length = $(this).closest('.videoList').find('.slider').length;
  alert(`length A = ${length}`);
});

function btnClick() {
  var length = $(this).closest('.videoList').find('.slider').length;
  alert(`length B = ${length}`);
}

document.querySelector('.navBtn').addEventListener('click', btnClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="videoList">
  <div class="navBtn">Button</div>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li>items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically, try to avoid inline event handlers in general.  Separate the markup from the code, and assign the event handlers in code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both an event attribute and a jQuery event, so just use the jQuery one. Event attributes like `onclick=` are discouraged. Also, you should use an `<input type="range">` for sliders.

```js
$('.navBtn').on('click', function() {
  var length = $(this).closest('.videoList').find('.slider').val();
  alert(`length A = ${length}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="videoList">
  <button class="navBtn">Button</button>
  <input class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="100" />
</section>
```